# Database - Using group by without grouping result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
Product_ID | Size_ID
         3 |      S
         3 |      M
         4 |      L
         5 |      S
```

And I would like the result to be like:

```
Product_ID | Size_ID
         3 |   M, S
         4 |      L
         5 |      S
```

Is it possible to do that? My query is this:

```
Select Product_ID, Size_ID
FROM product
Group by Product_ID
Order by Product_ID Desc
```

Comment: GROUP BY is typically used together with aggregate functions, like SUM, COUNT, MAX etc. I think MySQL supports the non-standard group_concat function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function should do the trick:

```
Select   Product_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(Size_ID ORDER BY Size_ID)
FROM     product
Group by Product_ID
Order by Product_ID Desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try group_concat:

```
Select Product_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(Size_ID)
FROM product
Group by Product_ID
Order by Product_ID
```